# Encrypted drive installation possible?

Tags: linux, vmware, installation

Is VMware capable of installing a Linux host, Windows Vista guest configuration on an encrypted `/home` drive in Linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. VMWare sticks its data in files, and those can live on pretty much any reasonable file system, whether there is an encryption layer below it or not.